# Use a variable from a function in a DepdencyInjection Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with a dependency injection in my project. I was wondering if it is possible to set the ip of my server as a variable. My dependency injection looks like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthApi(): AuthAPI {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://IP-ADDRESS:8080/")
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSharedPref(app: Application): SharedPreferences {
        return app.getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthRepository(api: AuthAPI, prefs: SharedPreferences): AuthRepository {
        return AuthRepositoryImplementation(api, prefs)
    }
}
```

Now I would like to use a variable from a different file as my .baseUrl(). The variable is coming from a seperate screen looking like this:

```
@Composable
@Destination(start = true)
fun AuthScreen(
    navigator: DestinationsNavigator,
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {    
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val dataStore = StoredServerIP(context)

    val savedServerIP = dataStore.getServerIP.collectAsState(initial = "")

    val state = viewModel.state
    //irrelevant code
}
```

Back to my question: is it possible to use the "val savedServerIP" value as my baseUrl? I tried calling the provideAuthApi() function in my screen and passing the value as a parameter, which didn't quite work. I also tried refering to the variable with imports which also didn't work. Any solutions/work arounds for this?

Comment: "which didn't quite work" Could you elaborate on that one?

Comment: Sure, I tried passing my ip as a parameter to my dependecy injection function directly like this: `@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthApi(ip : String): AuthAPI {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://$ip:8080/")
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create()
    }` and call it directly in my screen like this: `provideAuthApi(savedServerIP.toString())`. When I run my code it throws this error:`[Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency injection idea is basically hand over creating objects by someone else but the creation itself is quite similar. So If you want to inject an string, Just provide it! Here is an example

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideBaseUrl(): String {
        return "http://IP-ADDRESS:8080"
    }

@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthApi(
    url:String,
    ): AuthAPI {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create()
    }
```

---

**Update**
If you want to get that string from user or somewhere else you can store the address and then retrieve it in your module.

```
interface SpLocalDataSource {
    fun setIp(ip: String)

    fun getIp(): String?
}
```

```
class SpLocalDataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
) : SpLocalDataSource {

    override fun setIp(ip: String) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("ip", ip).apply()
    }

    override fun getIp(): String? {
        return = sharedPreferences.getString("ip", null) ?: null
    }

}
```

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSpLocalDataSource(
        sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    ): SpLocalDataSource {
        return SpLocalDataSourceImpl(sharedPreferences)
    }
```

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthApi(
    spLocalDataSource: SpLocalDataSource,
    ): AuthAPI {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(spLocalDataSource.getIp())
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create()
    }
```

Now you can inject SpLocalDataSource in your repository and/or viewmodel (depends on your structure).
Eg:

```
class RepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val spLocalDataSource: SpLocalDataSource,
) : Repository {

    override fun setIp(ip:String) {
        spLocalDataSource.setIp(ip)
      }

    override fun getIp(): String? {
        return spLocalDataSource.getIp()
      }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I also tried something like this but my problem is that I want to set my "IP-ADDRESS" in an input field for the user in my application. So I have to pass the IP as a variable from a different file to the function "provideBaseUrl()". This throws the same error as my comment above shows. Thanks for your response though!

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood the question. Hope my updated answer help you with that.